# using tags to detect if something was tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uistoryboard

I have a `UITableView` where I have some cells that are tappable and some cells that have a `UISwitch`. I thought that the best way to detect if a `UITableView` or `UISwitch` was tapped is to use tags.

[image]

I have added the tags for these items, but I'm not too sure how to code it in order for the detection to occur. How can I do this?

Note: I realize that this is iOS 7, but since Apple has allowed all developers to submit apps now, I think it's safe to assume that it's not under NDA anymore.

Comment: If you need to identify what row was tapped, you can't do it this way in IB. You need to add the tags in code and tie them to the value of indexPath or indexPath.row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Grzegorz Krukowski answer shows you how to get a hold of your switch in code.

You'll also need to set up a method to be called once your switch has been tapped. The way to do it is as such:

Get a reference to your switch, perhaps in `viewDidLoad`

`UISwitch *label = (UISwitch *)[self.view viewWithTag:2];`

Then set up a method to run once the control event is triggered

```
[label addTarget:self action:@selector(switchValueChanged:) 
            forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

- (void)switchValueChanged:(UISwitch *)switch {
    // Do something here....
}
```

Does your tableview scroll? If the cell containing the switch is scrolled off screen, you might have some trouble accessing it due to the way table views recycle cells. The code abouve assumes you won't have this issue.

Comment: I get an error when using the first line of code; I got rid of the error when I added `self.view` instead of just `self`. I'll still mark it as correct; thanks for your help.

Comment: ah yes apologies! Thanks for pointing that out, I've updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

```
 UISwitch *label = (UISwitch *)[self viewWithTag:2];
```

Advice: If you don't use properties to keep reference to those items - make sure you have something better than just 1, 2, 3 in code. Make enumarations for those elements for example:

```
 typedef enum {
     kUIElementTableView,
     kUIElementSaveSwitch
 } UIElements;

 UISwitch *label = (UISwitch *)[self viewWithTag:kUIElementTableView];
 UISwitch *label = (UISwitch *)[self viewWithTag:kUIElementSaveSwitch];
```